# Android tab button stylizing

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I'm working through a project where we are removing the ActionBarSerlock from an older project.  I'm trying to rebuild the tab bar to look like the original bar where each tab looks like an actual button.  For now the look must be kept the same.  This is what the current tab bar looks like:
[image: Sherlock Tab Bar]

I've been able to get the shading to work and the icon/text to be displayed as needed, but having problems in getting the button to fill the entire tab and I need to put in the divider lines to make them look like buttons as above.  This is basically what I have so far (This is just a test project so the images are not the exact same quality images as the first image):
[image: ActionBar Tabs]

So I need to figure out how to expand the tab buttons to fill the entire tab position and how to create the separator lines to make them look like real buttons.  A lot of the code below is from the original project that had the ActionBarSerlock in it and I haven't been able to identify exactly where the button layouts were being created unless it was built into that library.  So I've just been trying to piecemeal things together to create the same look and feel.

This is what I'm doing in the main Activity to fill the tabs:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.navigation_logo);
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    View tab1View = View.inflate(this, R.layout.tab_accounts, null);
    TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tab1View);
    tabLayout.addTab(tab1);

    View tab2View = View.inflate(this, R.layout.tab_pay_transfer, null);
    TabLayout.Tab tab2 = tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tab2View);
    tabLayout.addTab(tab2);

    View tab3View = View.inflate(this, R.layout.tab_rdc, null);
    TabLayout.Tab tab3 = tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tab3View);
    tabLayout.addTab(tab3);

    View tab4View = View.inflate(this, R.layout.tab_more, null);
    TabLayout.Tab tab4 = tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tab4View);
    tabLayout.addTab(tab4);

    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Log.d("TEST", "Getting Item: " + tab.getPosition());
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

The is an example of the code for the first tab (tab_accounts.xml).  I had tried to play with putting in divider lines but wasn't sure if that was the best way to do them or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab_container"
    style="@style/tab_container"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient">

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/divider_color" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tab_image"
        style="@style/tab_image"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/tab_accounts_selector" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_text"
        style="@style/tab_text"
        android:text="Accounts" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/divider_color" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the styles that are being used in the above tab layout:

```
<style name="tab_container">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="tab_image">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/tab_accounts_selector</item>
</style>

<style name="tab_text">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:text">Accounts</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/tab_text_color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
</style>
```

I didn't include the selector files since I didn't think they were really relavent to the changes needed.  But if them or any other coding is needed to help determine the changes needed let me know and I'll supply them.

Like I mentioned, this is going into an older project so I'm trying to keep from having to restructure it as much as possible.

I appreciate any help possible.  Thank you.

Comment: Just set the TabBar background to the gradient and each tab layout background to transparent. I also suggest Following Material Design Guidelines. You can't go wrong with their design patter. You will see that you probably dont need dividers. https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-usage

Comment: We've already tried to push the newer design specs to our client but for now they insist that it remains the same so I've got to get the dividers into it somehow.